# Fetch Firebase child data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I already have setup Firebase on Xcode 9.

**My question:**
I want to retrieve data from Firebase. This works but when I add another text in a group it wont retrieve.

**Example**

FIREBASE:

```
lang :

  "Deutsch"

  "Englisch"
```

Firebase Image Example because it's difficult to explain:

[image: Firebase Image Example beacause it's difficult to explain]

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outputone: UILabel!
    // @IBOutlet weak var outputtwo: UILabel!

    var dbReference: DatabaseReference?
    var dbHandle: DatabaseHandle?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dbReference = Database.database().reference()
        // dbReference?.child("lang").childByAutoId().setValue("Deutsch")
        // dbReference?.child("lang").childByAutoId().setValue("Englisch")

        // retrieve data
        dbHandle = dbReference?.child("lang").observe(.childAdded, with:{ (snapshot) in
            let lang:String? = snapshot.value as? String
            self.outputone.text = (lang)
        })

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I want that "Deutsch" displays in outputone and "Englisch" in outputtwo

Can someone help ?

Comment: what is the current output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you retrieve the entire `lang` node. So the [snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot) you get from Firebase contains both `"de": "Deutch"` and `"en": "English"`. When you now do `snapshot.value as? String`, it returns `nil` since the snapshot doesn't have a single, simple string value.

To get the specific values, you first need to tell the snapshot which child property you want: `de` or `en`, and *then* you can get the string value.

```
dbHandle = dbReference?.child("lang").observe(.value,  with:{(snapshot) in
    let de:String? = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath:"de").value as? String
    let en:String? = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath:"en").value as? String
    self.outputone.text = (de)
    self.outputtwo.text = (en)
})
```

Comment: Do you have another idea ?

Comment: It display nil nil nil nil

Comment: Ah, I now see you had a `childAdded` listener that I copied. You should use a `value` observer with my code. I updated my answer. If it doesn't work for you, step through it in a debugger, set a breakpoint in the completion handler, and inspect what the snapshot is. Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so you will have to provide that information in order for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

when retrieving the data from Firebase, it's come as a chunk. This is when the downCasting comes in handy.

```
dbHandle = dbReference?.child("lang").observe(.childAdded,  with:{(snapshot) in

    guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any],
    let de = dictionary["de"] as? String, 
    let en = dictionary["en"] as? String else {
    "error occurs when down casting.."
     return}

   self.outputone.text = de
   self.outputwo.text = en 
})
```

whenever dealing with a dictionary approach, it's dangerous to hardcode string key every time. it's error-prone. I recommend you create a struct holding each key so you don't need to type string every time needed.